# how to update recycleview when data is inserted in firebase?

Tags: android

How can i implement a listener on firebase to keep check if data has changed in firebase? for example, a user insert a data in firebase, a second user is checking a listview of that data, i want to refresh that listview automatically.

Comment: is your question about adding data to ListView or getting data from firebase realtime ?

Comment: I recommend you to use FirestoreRecyclerAdapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen to Firebase Database changes, and once data added to the database, you will be notified on client side and you will receive the data that is added to firebase database because it's realtime database.

```
mFirebaseDatabase.child("yourNode").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
 @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            // here you need to handle the value added.
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways.

Way 1: If possible, create a callback and after user insert a new item, you callback will fire.

Way 2: Every N second (2-5), you could make a request to server to ask him if new data avaliable.

Also if you are building a list with recyclerView, for efficient updating list, use [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil).
Which case is better, you decide. I don't work with firebase list.

Comment: Voted up, but I don't think that requesting every 2 seconds is a good solution, it's better to listen to the Firebase Database changes and add the data added, because it's realtime database so why don't we take this feature of firebase database ?

Comment: @KhalidTaha I did not work with firebase if it possible to listen for update it is great, this solutions will be perfect.